# Replacing a string value in PHP

Tags: php, templates

I'm trying to make this code more flexible:

```
<?php echo str_replace('class="google"', 'class="google" item="google"', $_coreHelper->currency($_price, true, true)); ?>
```

I have edited it to include `<?php echo $_Helper?>`:

```
<?php echo str_replace('class="google"', 'class="google" item="<?php echo $_Helper?>"', $_coreHelper->currency($_price, true, true)); ?>
```

but it not working. It shows:

```
<span class="google" item="<?php echo $_Helper?>">
```

in my template.

Answer (score 1):

No need for php tags anymore inside that, just concatenate the value properly inside the replacement:

```
echo str_replace(
    'class="google"', 
    'class="google" item="'.$_Helper.'"', 
    $_coreHelper->currency($_price, true, true)
);
```

Sidenote: By the way, as your project goes along and something complicated has stumped you because of complex string manipulation, you might consider using an HTML Parser instead. `DOMDocument` in particular.

Answer (score 0):

php code into php tag

```
<?php echo str_replace('class="google"', 'class="google" item="'.$_Helper.'"', $_coreHelper->currency($_price, true, true)); ?>
```